# Does the following limit exist? $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left(\frac{(x^4+y^4) \sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2+y^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm having some trouble solving the following limit:

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left(\frac{(x^4+y^4) \sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2+y^2}\right)$

Wolfram is suggesting that it doesn't exist. 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%5B%28x%5E4%2By%5E4%29sin%281%2Fx%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2C+x+to+0%2C+y+to+0%5D

Can you point out where I am making a mistake?

$0 \le \lvert \frac{(x^4+y^4) \sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2+y^2} \rvert \le \lvert \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \rvert \le \lvert \frac{x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \rvert = \lvert x^2+y^2 \rvert \to 0 $ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ By the squeeze theorem I get that the limit is $0$. Any help is appreciated c:

Comment: Sounds good to me. Using polar coordinates, $f(x,y)=r^2(cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)\sin(\frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)})$, so $|f(x,y)|\leqslant 2r^2=2(x^2+y^2)$ , similar to the ineqaulity you found.

Comment: @Rafał Szypulski You are right and WA is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason WA says this limit does not exist is because the expression is not well defined for $x=0,y\neq 0$, and that is one direction along which you can approach $(0,0)$.

You can extend your function to one which is defined everywhere except $(0,0)$ by adopting the (sensible) convention that $0\sin(1/0)=0$. This function would indeed tend to $0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a good way to solve it. I think WA is wrong. What i can suggest is to use polar coordinates, they help solve the problem of finding the limits quite fast.